# Is it possible to configure detox to only run a subset of the matched *.spec.js files?

Tags: jestjs, detox

As far as I can tell from the Detox docs, issues, and StackOverflow questions, there is no way to configure Detox so it only runs a subset of the matched tests (*.spec.js).

Does anyone know how to do this? I want to ask on here before I file an issue on the repo.

Most of the time it's desirable to simply run all matched tests . But in certain scenarios, it would be nice to only run a subset.

For example: I want to use Jest for 1) Acceptance tests + PR gating and 2) Traversing the app and generating screenshots of the various screens. Use case 1 is fast and lightweight. Use case 2 is expensive and will take a long time.

For each use case, I only want to run the tests *for that use case*. Does any know how to do this? I can think of several hacky approaches (file renaming, conditional logic in tests that keys on env variables, etc...), but I think this should be a supported thing.